# Moving New Image File name from controller to model

Tags: php, sql, model-view-controller

I need a little help moving my new image file path from the controller to the model, with the current code below if I printr at point of executing it gives  all the correct values, once I execute with the query it throws up this error

Notice: Undefined index: image_path in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\models\Admin.php on line 17

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:

Here is my controller code

```
public function addnew(){
                if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
                    $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                    $data = [ 
                        'fname' => trim($_POST['fname']),
                        'lname' =>  trim($_POST['lname']),
                        'email' =>  trim($_POST['email']),
                        'contact' =>  trim($_POST['contact']),         
                        'jobrole' =>  trim($_POST['jobrole']),
                        'bio' =>  trim($_POST['bio']),
                        'role'=> 'Service Advisor',
                        'password' => trim($_POST['password']),
                        'confirm_password' =>  trim($_POST['confirm_password']),
                        'fname_err' => '',
                        'lname_err' => '',
                        'email_err' => '',
                        'contact_err' => '',
                        'jobrole_err' => '',
                        'bio_err' => '', 
                        'password_err' => '',
                        'confirm_password_err' => ''     
              ];
                 //Validate
                    if(empty($data ['email'])){
                        $data['email_err'] = 'Please enter an Email Address';
                    } else {
                       if($this->adminModel->findUserByEmail($data['email'])){
                        $data['email_err'] = 'That email Already Exists';       
                       }                
                    }        
                       if(empty($data ['fname'])){
                        $data['fname_err'] = 'Please enter a First Name';
                    }
                       if(empty($data ['lname'])){
                        $data['lname_err'] = 'Please enter a Last Name';
                    }

                        if(empty($data ['contact'])){
                        $data['contact_err'] = 'Please enter a Telephone Number';
                    }
                        if(empty($data ['jobrole'])){
                        $data['jobrole_err'] = 'Please enter a Job Role';
                    }
                        if(empty($data ['bio'])){
                        $data['bio_err'] = 'Please enter a short Bio';
                    }

                       if(empty($data ['password'])){
                        $data['password_err'] = 'Please enter a Password';
                    } else if (strlen($data['password']) < 6){
                           $data['password_err'] = 'Password must be 6 characters';         
                       }

                      if(empty($data ['confirm_password'])){
                        $data['confirm_password_err'] = 'Please confirm your Password';
                    } else {

                        if($data['password'] != $data['confirm_password']){
                            $data['confirm_password_err'] = 'Passwords dont match';
                        }
                      }      
        //Make sure errors are empty
                    if (empty($data['email_err']) &&  empty($data['fname_err']) && empty($data['lname_err']) && empty($data['contact_err']) && empty($data['jobrole_err']) && empty($data['bio_err'])  && empty($data['password_err']) && empty($data['confirm_password_err'])){
             //Hash Password
                $data['password'] = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            //Work With Image      
                $image_path     = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
                $temp_file_name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
                $file_size      = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"];
                $target_dir     = "../public/ProfilePics/ServiceAdvisors/";
                $new_name       = $target_dir.time()."-".rand(1000, 9999)."-".$image_path;
                $upload_ok      = 1;
                $img_file_type  = pathinfo($new_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $check_img = getimagesize($temp_file_name);     
                $_POST['image_path'] = $new_name;

                if($check_img == false) {

                    $upload_ok = 0;

                    } else {
                        if($file_size > 500000) {

                            $upload_ok = 0;
                        } else {
                            if($img_file_type != "jpg" && $img_file_type != "png" && $img_file_type != "jpeg" && $img_file_type != "gif") {

                                $upload_ok = 0;
                            } else {
                                if($upload_ok === 0) {

                                } else {
                                    if(move_uploaded_file($temp_file_name, $new_name)){

                         $this->adminModel->addnew($data);
                         redirect ('administrator/serviceadvisors');
                       }
                else {
                           die();
                       }
                  }
                 }

             }         
                       };

                    } else {              
                        $this->view('administrator/addnew', $data);
                    }      
                } else {
                //ReLoad Form and keep details
              $data = [
                  'fname' => '',
                  'lname' => '',
                  'email' => '',
                  'contact' => '',
                  'jobrole' => '',
                  'bio' => '',
                  'password' => '',
                  'confirm_password' => '',
                  'fname_err' => '',
                  'lname_err' => '',
                  'email_err' => '',
                  'contact_err' => '',
                  'jobrole_err' => '',
                  'bio_err' => '',
                  'password_err' => '',
                  'confirm_password_err' => ''

              ];
                    $this->view('administrator/addnew', $data);
                }       
            }

        }
```

And here is my Model Code

```
public function addnew($data){
                $this->db->query('INSERT INTO advisors (fname, lname, email, contact, jobrole, bio, image_path, role, password) VALUES(:fname, :lname, :email, :contact, :jobrole, :bio, :image_path :role, :password ) ');
                $this->db->bind(':fname', $data['fname']);
                $this->db->bind(':lname', $data['lname']);
                $this->db->bind(':email', $data['email']);
                $this->db->bind(':contact', $data['contact']);
                $this->db->bind(':jobrole', $data['jobrole']);
                $this->db->bind(':bio', $data['bio']);
                $this->db->bind(':image_path', $data['image_path']);
                $role = 'Service Advisor';
                $this->db->bind(':role', $data['role']);
                $this->db->bind(':password', $data['password']);
                if ($this->db->execute()){
                return true;   
                } else {
                return false;
            }

        }
```

And this is my form, I am not going to post al the form as I know the area at fault

```
<fieldset class="form-group floating-label-form-group mb-1">
<label for="fileToUpload">Upload Profile Pic: <sup>*</sup></label>
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" class="form-control round" value="<?php echo 
$data['fileToUpload'];?>" accept="image/*" >
 <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $data['fileToUpload_err'];?></span>
 </fieldset>
```

Liek mentioned earlier it is to get the image_path into the Model so I can upload it to the db, the image is saving in the correct folder its just not sending the image_path

Any help much appreciated

Comment: It looks like you are setting the image_path in the $_POST array, but it is expected in the $data array.

Comment: I have set it within the data but it throws anther error, I will have another go shortly and let you know the error I am getting then

Comment: Hi Rob, just to let you know I finally managed to sort it, stupidly if you have a look at the query line in my model code you will see the missing comma after the :image_path value.  :o(

Comment: Ahhh, it's the little things that get you! Glad you figured it out.